# Как зафиксировать текст

Tags: html, html5, joomla, joomla3

Как зафиксировать текст, что бы при разных разрешениях он не делился пополам, а переносился полностью?

Answer (score 0):

В css для него прописать

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

```css
body { width: 10em }
p { outline: 1px dotted red }
span { color: blue }
.nbr { white-space: nowrap }
```

```html
<p>Some text <span>don't break me</span> Some other text</p>
<p>Some text <span class=nbr>don't break me</span> Some other text</p>
<p>Some text <span class=nbr>don't break me but be carefull with length</span> Some other text</p>
```

Comment: Можно чуть чуть по подробнее?

Comment: @Антон, готово.